# dpkg error exit status 2

Tags: php, ubuntu, gd, dpkg

Trying to build php from source on Ubuntu 9.10 to enable GD2, but when i run dpkg-buildpackage, it just quits giving me this error:

> QUILT_PATCHES=debian/patches quilt --quiltrc /dev/null pop -a -R || test $? = 2
>   Patch suhosin.patch does not remove cleanly (refresh it or enforce with -f)
>
> make: *** [unpatch] Error 1
>   dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2

I've googled around, but i really can't find what's causing this, and what i should do about it...

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you used source from debian package? If no, then you can have difficulties to apply patches from Debian. Debian uses primary clean sources (package_name.orig.tar.gz file) and patches (package_name.diff.gz). Don't know about this particular problem, didn't build packages for some time, but you could try to build it debian-way (http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-sourcepkgs). Ckech out original sources, then apply Debian patches, apply your patches (or the other order, don't know which way should work), and finally build Debian packages from patched sources

Comment: i got the source by using "apt-get source". From my understanding, this should download the officially supported PHP version's source.

To build it, i've tried using dpgk-buildpackage unsuccessfully, but i've also tried to do it manually via ./configure make make install, but that way, i cant get the ./configure options right...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar trouble recently.  What's happening is that dpkg is trying to apply patches to the source code, after you've already applied a patch.  It can't apply them cleanly because they have gotten moved around by your modifications.  I fiddled for a while, and found out that the easiest thing to do is to add the patch to [Quilt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quilt_(software)) and then build the package.  BUT, the "patch directory" for quilt is DIFFERENT from the normal one, in a Debian package.  It's `debian/patches` rather than `./patches`.

Anyway, look at section 6.4 in this page of the Debian package maintainer's guide:  http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/ch-build.en.html